# Doubt in MODIS NDVI range

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modis, ndvi

[image]MODIS-NDVI product MOD13Q1 shows range from -1986 to 9976 but NDVI ranges from -1 to 1. What these value means? What do I need to do as corrections?

I have attached an image showing MODIS-NDVI ranges in ArcGIS.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84058/reprojected-modis-ndvi-has-range-from-32768-to-32767-expected-1-to-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MOD13Q1 product has a scale factor of 0.0001 - this can be seen under "layers" at [the MOD13Q1 product page](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mod13q1).

Applying this scale factor gives you NDVI values between -0.2 and 1.

Comment: Thank you Mikkel Lydholm. It was really helpful. I am now able to get NDVI values within the range of -1 to 1.

I multiplied the scale factor with  my MODIS product in Raster Calculator in ArcGIS. Now I am getting the values ranging between -0.1986 to 0.9976. Am I on a right track? This is the right way to do this?.

Comment: Yes. That is the correct way of doing it, @AnujaNegi