# Scaling factor for MODIS (MY09GA 006 or MYDTBGA 006) product for timeseries data

Tags: modis, ndvi, envi

I was using Modis data (MYDO9GA) product for my research and I was following this document as a user guide.

https://landweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/QA_WWW/forPage/user_guide/MOD09_UserGuide_v1.4.pdf

I applied the scaling factor (0.0001) and valid range filter (-100 to 16000  from document) on my albedo data (from MYDTGA006 product) but  values do not seem normal. For example  I am getting values between -0.12 to 0). However albedo range should be between 0-1. I was not using raster data. I extracted time series data based on lat long using following link.   https://lpdaacsvc.cr.usgs.gov/appeears/

I think scaling is not necessary for timeseries point data.For example solar zenith data looks fine without scaling factor. I was wondering if anyone has experience with his data product timeseries.

Also link to the question asked previously to provide context. Again I am not using raster image (like used in the question below). I am using timeseries data.
[Reprojected MODIS NDVI has range from -32768 to 32767, expected -1 to 1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84058/reprojected-modis-ndvi-has-range-from-32768-to-32767-expected-1-to-1/330029?noredirect=1#comment538236_330029)